# How to avoid per-site caching in django

Tags: django, caching

I didn't quite understand how per-view caching is activated in Django vs. per-site caching. Per-site caching (caching all views) is activated by the prescribed settings in the settings.py file (the CACHES block and adding the fetch and update middlewares). Per-view caching is done by adding the cache_page decorator only to desired views. but do I still need to have the middlewares defined as above? then what prevents the per-site caching to go in effect?